# shorten if statement with indexOf

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if statement.

```
if(content.indexOf("a") > -1 || content.indexOf("b") >-1 || content.indexOf("c") > -1 || content.indexOf("d") > -1)
```

Is there any solutions to shorten this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression...

```
if (content.match(/[abcd]/))
```

Or a simple loop might be more appropriate, depending on what your real data looks like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].forEach(function (char) {
  if (content.indexOf(char) > -1) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: The "simple loop" example is not strictly equivalent to the `if` condition in the question. The answer here will execute the body more than once if `content` contains both "a" and "b". The correct way to do this would be using `.some`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
if (content.match(/[abcd]/))
```

or even shorter

```
if (content.match(/[a-d]/))
```

Comment: Could be even shorter with `[a-d]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, I ll leave the [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method here.

```
if (["a", "b", "c", "d"].some(function(char) {
    return content.indexOf(char) !== -1;
})) {
    ...
}
```